# For loop to create Scatter chart with CanvasJs using Django data as input

Tags: javascript, python, django, canvas, html5-canvas

I found that I can create nice scatter plot with CanvasJS into my HTML templates (see the link: http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-scatter-chart/)

I am creating a website using Django and a MySQL database.
In one of my tables (models) I have 3 fields VARCHAR containing different values:
 - the 1st field contains values for X axis.
 - The 2nd field contains values for Y axis.
 - The 3rd field contains one letter labels.

Here is an example for one entry if it is not clear:

1st field:

```
999.99;-89.01;-60.29;-145.83;-140.76;-148.24;-88.70;56.92;69.08;-121.37
```

2nd field:

```
143.12;146.51;143.73;177.58;121.68;116.45;-14.05;20.77;15.82;168.20
```

3rd field:

```
CPPEEECTTE
```

As you can see, values are separated by ";" in fields 1 and 2.
there are 10 values in field 1, 10 values in field 2, and 10 corresponding  letter labels.
All fields are 1 long string.

So my question is simple, I don't know how to make a for loop in javascript so that those coordinates will be taken in the scatter chart.

Here is the example of the canvasjs for scatter chart I want to obtain:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
     title:{
      text: "Title of my scatter chart"
    },

    data: [
    {
     type: "scatter",
     dataPoints: [

     { x: 999.99, y: 143.12 },
     { x: -89.01, y: 146.51 },
     { x: -60.29, y: 143.73 },
     { x: -145.83, y: 177.58 },
     { x: -140.76, y: 121.68 },
     { x: -148.24, y: 116.45 }
     ]
   }
   ]
 });

chart.render();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want is to generate coordinates in dataPoints with a for loop. 
The 3 fields will be 3 rows in a HTML table.
The 3rd field will be used to associate a color to a letter. (Example: C = blue, P = green, E = yellow, T = red).

I have absolutely no idea how to make that in javascript. 
If someone is experienced in JS, I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by traversing the arrays(of x,y values and color) and converting them to the [format required by CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/working-with-data/) and then [updating the chart options](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/).

```
   for(var i = 0; i < xVal.length; i++) {
       chart.options.data[0].dataPoints.push({
           x: parseFloat(xVal[i]),
           y: parseFloat(yVal[i]),
           color: colorArr[i]
       });
   }
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mw3c51h/) for the same.

Comment: In my case Xs and Ys are not arrays, they are long strings.

Comment: Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mw3c51h/). The x and y values are strings.

Comment: jsfiddle seems indeed to do what I was looking for. it's too late now but thank you anyway, I accept your answer ;) !